# Finding in which division a point is in a wheel?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've got a wheel with $38$ divisions. If I place a random point on the wheel and get the angle where it's located, is there a formula that I could use to figure out in which division is the point located ? Any suggestions ?

I know that $\frac{360}{38}$ equals $9.473$. So, between $0$ and $9.473$ I find the first division.

[image]

Comment: Take the integer portion of your value divided by $360/n$.

Answer (score 1):

The angle of one division (in degree) $$=\frac{\text{total angle}}{\text{number of divisions}}$$$$=\frac{360}{38}=\frac{180}{19}$$ Now, assume a random point, on the wheel, making an angle say $\theta$ (in degree) in anticlockwise sense with the positive x-direction (taken as reference), hence the approximate number of divisions, in which the random point is located, is $$\frac{\theta}{\frac{180}{19}}=\frac{19(\theta)}{180}$$ It is to be that the number obtained may be a fraction hence we are to select a least natural $n$ such that $$\bbox[4pt, border: 1px solid blue;]{\color{blue}{(n-1)< \frac{19(\theta)}{180}\leq n}}$$
Hence, by knowing the angle $\theta$ (i.e. angular position of the random point say in C.C.W. direction) we can easily figure out the division $\color{blue}{n}$ (w.r.t. to the positive x-axis taken as reference line) in which the random point is located such that $\color{blue}{n}$ is the $\color{blue}{\text{least natural number}}$ duly satisfying the above inequality.